# Generate random password where first character is a letter

Tags: bash

The following is the Linux command I'm using to randomly generate the password for the user. I would like to add one constraint like the generated password first character must not be a number or special character it should always be alphabets. Could some experts please help me?

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9#_$' | head -c $((7+$RANDOM%13)) ; echo
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: rinse & repeat.  Look at your own command; play with the character set in `tr`, use `head -c 1` ...

Comment: shuf: `{ shuf -en 1 {a..z} {A..Z}; shuf -ren $((7 + RANDOM % 13)) {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9} '#' '$' _; } | paste -sd ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple idea would be to randomly generate a single-character string (only letters) and then append the results of a second randomly genarated multi-character string, eg:

```
$ pfx=$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z' | head -c1)
$ echo "${pfx}"
e
$ sfx=$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9#_$' | head -c $((7+$RANDOM%13)))
$ echo "${sfx}"
Vk8OxpNi9Gud
$ newpwd="${pfx}${sfx}"
$ echo "${newpwd}"
eVk8OxpNi9Gud
```